# Sklearn conflict in setup.py

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pypi

I'm developing a python package that requires scikit-learn as a dependency, so in the setup.py I have:

```py
install_requires=['scikit-learn>=0.20.0']
```

I upload the package to test.pypi.org and when tried to install it in a virtual env I get this error: "ERROR: Cannot install package because these package versions have conflicting dependencies."

```
The conflict is caused by:
    scikit-learn 0.24.1 depends on numpy>=1.13.3
    scikit-learn 0.24.0 depends on numpy>=1.13.3
    scikit-learn 0.23.2 depends on numpy>=1.13.3
    scikit-learn 0.23.1 depends on numpy>=1.13.3
    scikit-learn 0.23.0 depends on numpy>=1.13.3
    scikit-learn 0.22 depends on numpy>=1.11.0
    scikit-learn 0.21.0 depends on numpy>=1.11.0
    scikit-learn 0.20.3 depends on scipy>=0.13.3
```

Also tried with others versions of sklearn with the same errors

I tried to add numpy>=1.13.3 (and in other try numpy>=1.11.0) in my setup.py but then it says It can't find a distribution that satisfies the requirement

Any ideas of how this could be fixed? Thanks

Comment: which version of python are u using?

Comment: Tried in 3.6, 3.7 and 3.8

Comment: What version of pip are you running? (It's unlikely, but I have seen some weird errors as the [new dependency resolver](https://pyfound.blogspot.com/2020/03/new-pip-resolver-to-roll-out-this-year.html) is getting worked on). Can you share the pypi-test link?

Comment: I'm using pip 21.0.1, this is the [link](https://test.pypi.org/project/sklearn-genetic-opt/0.1.0.dev6/) for the pypi test package

Answer (score 0):

maybe try and download numpy required version from github page?